# Creating user profile for (SAML) claims users in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, claims-based-auth, trusted-identity-provider

I have activated (SAML) claims based authentication on SharePoint 2013 web application and most of the users are external who doesnt have a domain account. I can see that the User profiles got created for domain users but not for SAML claim users. Does SharePoint creates User profile for SAML claim users when they login for the first time?

Thanks

Comment: So you fixed the issue with permissions, what was the problem, the app pool account running UPS or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This process requires a few changes to the User Profile Service Application.

First, you need to map `SPS-ClaimProviderID` to the login attribute used for your SAML provider. The Profile Property `SPS-ClaimProviderType` should show as "Trusted".

The next step is change your Synchronization Connection to use the 'Trusted Identity Provider'. Once you perform a full synchronization, you should be set.

Comment: I was having permission problems with UserProfile DB thats y profiles were not created for SAML users. Fixed permissions problem and i can see that profiles got created now. Thanks.